# Convert Date Value to Specific Format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

How to convert any date format to a specified format in C#.

For example:

If Date Format is

```
14.11.2011 or 14/11/2011
```

Looking for a conversion function which converts into

```
yyyy-MM-dd format like 2011-11-14
```

Comment: Have you tried to search even a BIT?! [tag:DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime), [tag:DateTime-Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("14/11/2011"); // may need some Culture help here
Console.Write(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Appreciate your kind time to anwser rather than downvoting :)

Comment: @DarkRider You are welcome. However, three things: 1) Don't make assumptions about who voted up/down based on comments/answers. It's very possible *I* did down vote, and abatishchev did not. 2) Don't take down votes personally. 3) You could, possibly, have found an answer more quickly by searching. (although in this specific case, you did get a few answers *very* fast...)

Comment: Thanks andrew, But times downvote will discourage a fresher to ask a question in SO. such in my case :)

Comment: @DarkRider You are exactly right in a way: Down votes discourage the questions that get down voted. *That is exactly intended*. I've been down voted plenty of times; I learn from it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method, [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
 and [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

```
string customFormattedDateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Correct; The question is also asking about parsing, though. Or at least it seems logical to assume that, since it talks about an existing date format (which does not apply if you already have a `DateTime` object.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) methods to parse the string into a DateTime then you can use the [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) to return the date in the new format. For standard formatting check this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for custom date formats [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "May 29,2012";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt);

Response.Write(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```